# Fetch OUT parameter in SQLException

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

In my stored procedure I have the following statement

```
IF (sdate > sysdate)
            THEN
                RAISE exec_not_allowed;
                                returnval := sdate;

            END IF;
```

returnval  is IN OUT parameter in my procedure.

In java normally an OUT parameter is fetched by using:

```
callablestatement.getInt(2);
```

How can I receive returnval in Java if an exception is raised? The exception error code is captured in the Java `SQLException` part.

Comment: Isn't `returnval := sdate` an unreachable statement in any case?

Comment: @beerbajay I didn't get any such error when I compiled and ran procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you raising an exception at all in this situation? You should only really raise an exception in two situations:

1. You intend to catch the exception and deal with it appropriately in the calling code.
2. Something is wrong and you want your application to crash and burn.

You're not doing either of these things, and don't need to. You just want to stop the code running and "return" (it's a procedure) your value. In this case I would suggest using [`return`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/return_statement.htm#LNPLS01340).

`return` ends the execution of the anonymous block that contains it and, in a procedure, returns "control" to the calling statement. i.e. it fits the bill perfectly.

The following code assigns `sdate` to your `out` parameter before halting the execution of the procedure, using return. "More stuff" will never occur.

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure_one (returnval in out date) is
begin

   -- some stuff.
   if sdate > sysdate then
      returnval := sdate;
      -- we don-t want to continue any more if this is true.
      return;
   end if;
   -- more stuff.
end;
```

If you only want to assign `sdate` to `returnval` if the condition is *not* true then you simply swap round these two lines; maybe taking it out of the if statement to make it more obvious. This is what your code does at the moment as when you raise `exec_not_allowed` all execution is stopped.

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure_two (returnval in out date) is
begin

   -- some stuff.

   -- we don-t want to continue any more if this is true.
   if sdate > sysdate then
      return;
   end if;

   returnval := sdate;
   -- more stuff.
end;
```

In either case your Java call remains the same. In the first procedure (`my_procedure_one`) you'll get `sdate` returned and in the second a null, assuming that `returnval` hadn't been previously assigned.

Comment: So you mean to say if return, then more stuff will never occur? Code execution will not proceed further?

Comment: @Polappan, execution in this procedure will not proceed further, identically to a raised exception. However, you won't have raised an exception and a calling procedure will continue to run from the point that this procedure was called.

Comment: Ok, the reason why I asked this point is my more stuff is insert and update statements. So I would like to stop the procedure if the condition is true.

Comment: @Polappan, for all intents and purposes I believe this is what you need. You don't seem to want to raise an error just stop execution of the code at a certain point. Thanks Gaurav :-).

Comment: Yes you are right. I will try and test this. Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`returnval:=sdate;` is a dead code in your case ,because exception is raised before assigning value to `returnval`.But if you want to terminate your program execution then ,you'll not able to get any `returnval` from the proc call .

You can do it by creating a block inside your `procedure` .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp(returnval IN OUT date)
IS 
BEGIN
 :
 :
 BEGIN 
   IF (sdate > sysdate) THEN
         RAISE exec_not_allowed;
   END IF;

 EXCEPTION 
  WHEN exec_not_allowed THEN 
    returnval := sdate;   --after raising an exception you can assign it like this .

  raise_application_error
      (-20145                                      --sqlcode
      ,'Exception is raised for date'||returnval   --message
      );
 END;
EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  -- 
END temp;
```

Comment: What if it is like `returnval := sdate;
        raise_application_error (-20145, 'Error');` because I would like to return error code to my application.

Comment: @Polappan:Its not possible  to return the returnval from your proc in case of `raise_application_error`,can you tell me  why you want the value in case of exception .

Comment: I would like to display in application or with date the exception is raised and that's why I would like to return value from procedure.

Comment: @Polappan:Ok may be i understand your question wrong ,you can pass the `date` in the `raise_application_error` message ,with this way you can display the message for the date for which exception is been raised ..I have edited my post

Comment: Yes I was thinking something like  this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is raised , the procedure execution is terminated.

You cannot get a response.